# Why jquery validate is not working?

Tags: spring-mvc, jquery-validate

Im trying to validate a form for add a new user using spring mvc :P. I had already the server side validations working via Spring custom validators. But client side validation are allowing the form to be submitted. This is how Im doing it:

Including the javascript files:

```
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="resources/js/additional-methods.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The form before Spring send it to the browser:

```
 <c:url value="/AddUser" var="action"/>
            <form:form method="post" action="${action}" commandName="user" id="adduserform">

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="username"><spring:message code="user.form.username"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="username"/>${duplicated}</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="password"><spring:message code="user.form.password"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" maxlength="20"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password"/>${policyMessage}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="confirmPassword"><spring:message
                            code="user.form.password2"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:password path="confirmPassword" maxlength="20"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="description"><spring:message
                            code="user.form.description"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="description"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="description"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="role"><spring:message code="user.form.roles"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:select path="role" items="${rolesList}"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="blocked"><spring:message code="user.form.blocked"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="blocked" value="false"/></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="changePasswordAtLogon"><spring:message
                            code="user.form.changePasswordAtLogon"/></form:label></td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="changePasswordAtLogon" value="false"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<spring:message
                            code="user.form.submit"/>"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </form:form>
        </table>
        </form>
```

The form in the browser:

```
 <form id="adduserform" action="/AddUser" method="post">

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                    <td><input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    <td></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" maxlength="20"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label></td>
                    <td><input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" value="" maxlength="20"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="description">Description</label></td>
                    <td><input id="description" name="description" type="text" value=""/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="role">User type</label></td>
                    <td><select id="role" name="role"><option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Administrator</option><option value="ROLE_USER">Normal User</option></select></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="blocked">Blocked</label></td>
                    <td><input id="blocked1" name="blocked" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_blocked" value="on"/></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><label for="changePasswordAtLogon">Change password at logon</label></td>
                    <td><input id="changePasswordAtLogon1" name="changePasswordAtLogon" type="checkbox" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="_changePasswordAtLogon" value="on"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </form>
```

The validation settings just below the form. Im just testing so theres only validation for the first field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("#adduserform").validate(
                        {
                            rules: {
                                username: {
                                    required: true
                                }
                            },
                            messages: {
                                username: {
                                    required: "F** working"
                                }
                            }
                        });
            });
```

Comment: Check your console for JavaScript errors.  Unless your bad HTML is the issue, nothing in the JavaScript code you've shown us could be breaking this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, therefore, your `form` is invalid.

```
<form id="adduserform" action="/AddUser" method="post">
    <tr>
        ....
```

You cannot possibly have a `<form>` tag as a parent of a `<tr>` element.  Only `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>` elements can be a parent of `<tr>` elements.

See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

**NOTE**:  This bad markup is *likely not* your root problem as your exact code is working in my jsFiddle.  However, I've only tested this in one browser and until you fix the invalid HTML, your results may not be cross-browser compatible.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dby055z9/**

Comment: Its working now, the table above tr fixed the jquery validation.BTW Im using chrome 38 on utopic 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

It should be working. Make sure you include the proper path of jquery.validate.min.js. 
See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9uoyqw/). Tested using jquery 1.8.3. For a concrete example, you can refer [here](http://runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation).

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#adduserform").validate(
                {
                    rules: {
                        username: "required"
                    },
                    messages: {
                        username:  "Please enter username!"
                    }
                });
     });
```